# Workarounds for no 'rvalue references to *this' feature

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

I have a proxy container class around a movable object, and wish the proxy to be able to implicitly yield an rvalue reference to the underlying object, but only when the proxy itself is being moved.

I believe that I will be able to implement this behaviour as per proposal n2439 ["Extending move semantics to *this"](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2439.htm), but it is not yet available in a release of gcc and won't be for a while.

The code below is what I am ultimately aiming for, but is not currently possible. Until this feature is available to me, are there any equivalent workarounds?

```
template< class T >
struct movable_proxy {
    operator T&&() && {
        return std::move(value);
    }

    operator const T&() const& {
        return value;
    }

private:
    T value;
};
```

Comment: I think the closest you'll be able to get is a function that does the conversion explicitly, rather than having a conversion operator, so you'd have to say `convert_proxy(p)` which is overloaded for rvalues and lvalues to return either `T&&` or `const T&` ... but that makes the use of the proxy non-transparent, which is probably not what you want

Comment: Indeed it isn't: although workable, it couples the client code to the proxy. A converting constructor on the wrapped type would work too, but that couples the wrapped type to it...

Comment: Oh, that proposed syntax is _groovy_.

Comment: Uh...potentially wacky idea: would complete specialisation of std::move<movable_proxy<xyz>> to return xyz&& instead of movable_proxy<xyz>&& be completely insane?

Comment: I'm curious. Sorry for the lack of understanding, but I would like to get it. If you remove the newly proposed `&&` and `&` modifiers, what are you missing exactly?

Comment: For the record, [give it a go in](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8610728/560648) [clang 2.9](http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C++0xCompilerSupport).

Comment: @AndyProwl: in that case, the proxy can convert into both `T const&` and `T&&`, irrespective of the value-category of the proxy itself. *I think*, the OP wants `proxy&&` to convert into `T&&` and `proxy&` into `T const&`.

Comment: @boycy, wouldn't you want to specialize `std::forward` not `std::move`? The latter always converts to an rvalue, even if the source wasn't an rvalue. And that only helps if the proxy object is explicitly moved/forwarded, not if it's just returned as an rvalue

Comment: @JonathanWakely: How does `std::forward` even make sense in this context, as `T` is not *deduced* type?

Comment: @Nawaz: so the wording "only when the proxy itself is movable" should be understood as "only when the proxy object is being moved", is it so?

Comment: @AndyProwl: I think so. :-)

Comment: Does anybody know why this feature hasn't made it into gcc?

Comment: Shameless plug for the unaware: [What is "rvalue reference for *this"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610571/what-is-rvalue-reference-for-this)

Comment: @Xeo: seven comments up!

Comment: @Non-StopTimeTravel my v3.0 clang barfs out with errors galore on standard header inclusions :-(

Comment: @Omnifarious, simply because it hasn't been implemented yet.  It's the last core language feature missing, but there's far less demand (or IMHO need) for it than lambdas, rvalue references etc. It will be in GCC 4.9, possibly even 4.8.x for some `x > 0`

Comment: @boycy: thank you, then I do understand and can appreciate the question. +1 ;-)

Comment: @JonathanWakely (doomed by too-speedy reply bypassing brain); specialising `std::forward` won't help where client code calls `std::move(movable_proxy<T>&)` expecting a `T&&` back.
I think for `std::forward` to return the appropriate `movable_proxy<T>` reference, i.e. to forward the proxy _as a proxy_ ,would be generally appropriate.

Comment: [With clang 3.2 it compiles just fine](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3LzsuC$2)

Comment: You can't partially specialize function templates, and you are not allowed to put overloads into `namespace std` - sorry, but I don't think there's any way to transparently "emulate" ref-qualifiers. The client needs to do *something* other than simply `std::move(o)`.

Comment: @Xeo: `You can't partially specialize function template` Wasn't that restriction lifted in C++11? Is this simply a matter of compiler support or am I remembering wrong?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I think it may've been considered at some point, but no the restriction was not lifted in C++11. This is inferred through existence of 14.5.5 _Class template partial specializations_ and no equivalent for function templates than being explicitly disallowed (at least as far as I can find).

Comment: @boycy: [You're right](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3716799/560648); [they were proposed](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html#229) in [n1295](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2001/n1295.asc) but ultimately rejected (and quite rightly so, since overloading does the job).

Comment: @boycy: _(cont.)_ ([I wasn't the first to think otherwise](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5101566/560648)) ([the day Xeo found this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688355/partial-specialisation-of-member-function-with-non-type-parameter#comment6497058_5688412)) ([related](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5002655/560648))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good question. I attempted writing a similar sort of proxy class recently but never achieved a good solution. The best I found was calling a member function on every use where the proxy was required to be an r-value:

```
ORef<T> move() {
    return ORef<T>( this->release() );
}
```

This changes the semantics of declaring something an r-value from `std::move(proxy)` to `proxy.move()`, but also allows the possibility of returning an object of a different type (implicitly convertible to your required type).

My coding practice using this was to always pass proxy objects as rvalues which forced manual specification of semantics (move, shared reference, copy or whatever), but that of course makes usage errors a potential problem (e.g. calling `x.move()` prior to the final usage of `x`).

Comment: Thanks @dhardy; I ended up with the exact same proxy type with a 'release' call and the same usage errors you mention. Pity there doesn't seem to be a workaround, but I guess that does make the case for the required language extension a good one.