# What does && mean at the end of a function signature (after the closing parenthesis)?

Tags: c++

In [Workarounds for no 'rvalue references to *this' feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14562984/workarounds-for-no-rvalue-references-to-this-feature), I see the following member function (a conversion operator):

```
template< class T >
struct A
{
    operator T&&() && // <-- What does the second '&&' mean?
    {
        // ...
    }
};
```

What does the second pair of `&&` mean?  I am not familiar with that syntax.

Comment: **&& ref-qualifier**: all declarations `T()` have a ref-qualifier: [**Link**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2439.htm)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

This is a ref-value qualifier. Here is a basic example:

```
// t.cpp
#include <iostream>

struct test{
  void f() &{ std::cout << "lvalue object\n"; }
  void f() &&{ std::cout << "rvalue object\n"; }
};

int main(){
  test t;
  t.f(); // lvalue
  test().f(); // rvalue
}
```

Output:

```
$ clang++ -std=c++0x -stdlib=libc++ -Wall -pedantic t.cpp
$ ./a.out
lvalue object
rvalue object
```

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610571/what-is-rvalue-reference-for-this).

Answer (score 48):

It indicates that the function can be invoked only on rvalues.

```
struct X
{
      //can be invoked on lvalue
      void f() & { std::cout << "f() &" << std::endl; }

      //can be invoked on rvalue
      void f() && { std::cout << "f() &&" << std::endl; }
};

X x;

x.f();  //invokes the first function
        //because x is a named object, hence lvalue

X().f(); //invokes the second function 
         //because X() is an unnamed object, hence rvalue
```

[**Live Demo**](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4Gr0VK%244) output:

```
f() &
f() &&
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes I found [*rvalue-reference to cv X" for functions declared with the && ref-qualifier*](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2439.htm) 13.3.1

Comment: Note that according to http://stackoverflow.com/a/8610714/368896, it's not legal to overload using `f()` and `f() &&` - "you are not allowed to overload between the r-value reference versions and the non-reference versions".

Comment: @DanNissenbaum: Yes, my LWS demo shows that. But because of power failure, I couldn't post that immediately. Updated it now.

Comment: Thanks.  What does LWS mean?  I cannot find it via Google - very few results appear for "LWS".

Comment: LWS stands for [www.liveworkspace.org](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4Gr0VK%244) where I've shown the demo.